# div to wrap the content even if window resize

Tags: html, css

I want the div to wrap the content even if window resize, When I resize browsers window content inside div goes outside of div, I tried to set floating on left side but I want both iframes in center

```
<div style="float:center; border: 3px ridge red; background: aqua; padding:12px">
<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <td>
    <center>
    <iframe width="600" height="371"></iframe>
    </center>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
    <center>
    <iframe width="600" height="371"></iframe>
    </center>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the `width:100%` instead `width:600` in `<iframe>`

```
<div style="float:center; border: 3px ridge red; background: aqua; padding:12px">
<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <td>
    <center>
    <iframe width="100%" height="371"></iframe>
    </center>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
    <center>
    <iframe width="100%" height="371"></iframe>
    </center>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guz5zxma/)

Alternate set `min-width`

```
<div style="float:center; border: 3px ridge red; background: aqua; padding:12px;min-width:1240px">
<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <td>
    <center>
    <iframe width="600" height="371"></iframe>
    </center>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
    <center>
    <iframe width="600" height="371"></iframe>
    </center>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[Fiddle Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/guz5zxma/1/)

Comment: Thank you sir, but It is resizing my iframes, I don't want to resize my iframes.